# Lineplot of proportions over year in SPSS

Tags: spss

Assume I have the following data

```
    DATA LIST FREE / sex (A) year.
BEGIN DATA
m 2011
m 2011
m 2012
f 2011
f 2011
f 2011
f 2011
f 2012
f 2012
END DATA.
```

How can I plot a line of how the proportions of males and females change over the years.
Not the absolute values and not the total percentages, but the percentages per year.

I also need a crosstab where the percentages per year are shown.

A syntax would be nice, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The crosstabs syntax would simply be `CROSSTABS TABLE Year By Sex /CELLS = Col.`. The graph you want you can actually build through the GUI, to use the summary functions per year though you need to specify the year variable as either ordinal or nominal.

Here is the GGRAPH code the GUI printed out for me. Clean up as needed.

```
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=year[LEVEL=ORDINAL] COUNT()[name="COUNT"] sex 
    MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: year=col(source(s), name("year"), unit.category())
  DATA: COUNT=col(source(s), name("COUNT"))
  DATA: sex=col(source(s), name("sex"), unit.category())
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("year"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Percent"))
  GUIDE: legend(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), label("sex"))
  SCALE: linear(dim(2), include(0))
  ELEMENT: line(position(summary.percent(year*COUNT, base.coordinate(dim(1)))), 
    color.interior(sex), missing.wings())
END GPL.
```